# How to change all component values of parent panel on change of child panel in wicket

Tags: wicket, wicket-6, wicket-1.6

In wicket I have created dynamic panels (parent panel) using list view in which I have to display the slider for that I have created another panel(child panel) to display the slider. Now the slider is created for each panel. On change of the slider in child panel I should do some calculation and change the values in parent panel where i moved the slider without refresh the page. is there any way to achieve this in wicket without using javascript

Answer (score 1):

The "Wicket way" would be to use Wicket Events with Broadcast.BUBBLE.
See example of Wicket events at http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/events/ and some documentation at http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/6.x/guide/advanced.html#advanced_2.

Send an event up to the parent. The event payload may bring the AjaxRequestTarget so that the parent can repaint itself if needed.

Comment: Why use an event with the target as a payload? Why not simply add the parent to the target in the child?

Comment: Yes. This is possible too. Do it if you are certain that the child component won't be used in different context, i.e. with a different parent in this or another application.

Comment: As i am using listview to populate the panels dynamically in which i have another child panel. How to repaint only correct parent object where i change the child panel. It should not repaint all the panels. It would be useful could you please share sample code for this

Comment: Better read the documentation, check the examples, try it and then if it doesn't work come back with your code so we can tell you what is wrong.